# Draft 2: Are my tectonic plate formations plausible?

Tags: internal-consistency, tectonics, maps

[image: Text]

Ignore the biomes and stuff, I’m going to change that later. The world is spherical, and this is a map of the whole world. A quick note: Fennalore, the continent in the middle of the bottom row, is where my story is mostly set. The awkward gap in the middle of it is caused by a growing rift between dimensions in the ocean there. Don’t worry about it.

Comment: You have a strange U-shaped plate between El’korrin, Fennalore, and Chinhuochou. I think the arms might better belong on other plates.

Comment: Assuming your world rotates East-to-West, your very massive plate Orriel is going to be pulled towards the equator by centripetal force. Over time, it should have already pushed a lot of the lighter plates around it out of the way, but - whatever the reason for where it is now - it should definitely be moving southward.

Comment: I see a lot of red lines along coasts.. you show your whole planet so the scale would be ok, but I wonder if "tectonic plates"really  run along coast lines all the time. On Earth that is not the case, the boundaries run mid sea, parallel to the coasts. I don't see that in above drawing, but I'm not going to put an answer (for lack of expertise) for Earth see https://www.google.com/search?q=tectonic+plates+map&tbm=isch

Comment: Finally, you have a lot of plates (28 by my count). Earth has 15. Is there a reason the crust on your world is so much more broken?

Comment: @JamesMcLellan - this is mercator projection, I'm not sure the plate is as large as it appears on the map. it is also polar.

Answer (score 1):

Mountain ranges associated with tectonic subduction zones are typically above the subducted part of the plate that subducts beneath the other plate.  The friction of the subduction causes the rock to be heated into magma, which then rises to the surface.  You wouldn't get a mountain range across the surface boundary between the two plates, you're actually more likely to get a trench unless both plates carry land masses toward the plate boundary.

You're only likely to get a mountain range over a plate boundary when - like the Himalayas - two land masses collide.  The lower plate's bedrock would subduct, while the lighter landmass rock would remain on the surface for the most part, and bunch up into mountains.

In particular, where two plates are colliding south of El'Korin, you'd likely get a chain of volcanic islands on one side of the boundary, and an ocean trench on the other side. The chart doesn't show which plate is subducting.

The areas where plates are pulling apart tend to be in the middle of oceans, roughly equidistant from both shores.  Where this sort of plate boundary occurs on land, you'd end up with cliffs to either side of a depression: a rift valley.  Eventually, when a rift valley connects to the sea, it would likely fill with water. You wouldn't get such separating plate boundaries on one side of a sea between two land masses, you'd get one midway between the two.

This map also doesn't seem to account for fault-lines that aren't on a plate boundary.  Plates don't always move in straight lines, some twist as they move, so there could be stresses that would cause faults.